# CSS: <DL> with spacing/margin between the dt/dd pairs

Tags: css

I have the following html:

```
<dl>
        <dt>Item 1</dt>
        <dd>
            <ul>
                <li>Value 1</li>
            </ul>
        </dd>
        <dt>Item 2</dt>
        <dd>
            <!-- this item is missing a value -->
        </dd>
        <dt>Item 3</dt>
        <dd>
            <ul>
                <li>Value 1</li>
                <li>Value 2</li>
                <li>Value 3</li>
            </ul>
        </dd>
    </dl>
```

I would like to lay it out like (instead of the normal dl which puts the term and definitions under each other):

```
Item 1    Value 1
Item 2    
Item 3    Value 1
          Value 2
          Value 3
```

Which is not a problem. The problem is that I would like to add a margin between each term/definition pair. The problem is that the definitions are not the same height (they range between 0 up to 5 list items), so I cannot apply the same margin on the dd tags.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

How's this?

```
dt, dd { display: block; float: left; margin-top: 20px; }
dt { clear: both; }
```

Comment: Don't forget dl { overflow: hidden; } ... :)

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean something like:

```
Item 1    Value 1

Item 2    

Item 3    Value 1
          Value 2
          Value 3
```

Because then I don't see why you can't apply the margin on the dd elements. I did a quick experiment, using the following CSS:

```
ul { 
  margin: -1.2em 0 0 100px; 
  padding: 0; 
}

dd { 
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Which appears to have the effect you need.

Answer (score 1):

Is your 'Item 2' dd truly empty or does it have a `&nbsp;` in it? If it is empty, it will be hard to get the dt/dd to line up correctly because the other dd's will have a height of 20px (for example) and the empty dd will have a height of 0.

Be careful with the margin-top, you will have to apply it to both the dt and dd.

I prefer to use padding on the bottom of the dd. It gives more consistent results.

```
dt {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 8em;
    }
 dd {
    margin: 0 0 0 9em;
     padding: 0 0 2.5em 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the proper use of `dl`, `dt` and `dd` is not using `ul` `li`'s within a `dd`, but instead use different `dd`'s. It seems to me you are using a list within an element which is itself for listing.

```
<dl>
    <dt>Item 1</dt>
    <dd>Value 1</dd>
    <dt>Item 2</dt>
    <dd>
       &nbsp;
    </dd>
    <dt>Item 3</dt>
    <dd>Value 1</dd>
    <dd>Value 2</dd>
    <dd>Value 3</dd>
</dl>
```

For CSS you could use this:

```
DL {
PADDING: 0; MARGIN: 0; }
DT {
POSITION: relative; PADDING: 0; MARGIN: 0; TOP: 1.2em; LEFT: 0px; }
DD {
PADDING: 0; MARGIN: 0 0 0 5em; }
```

Comment: It was meant as an example. But even still, the use of 3 DD is semantically different from a DD with a UL. 3 DDs mean that the Term has 3 Definitions. 1 DD with a UL means that the term has one definition that is build up from a list.

Comment: @Gidon These days Definition List has officially been "re-purposed" as Description List, so it is perfectly semantically valid to have 3 DDs for one DT. I realize that may not have been the case when this question was asked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help someone. I solved it by selecting all dt and dd elements, but the first row:

```
& > dt ~ dd + dt {
  margin-top: 0.75em;
}

// Select all dd but first row, this is the dd followed after the first dt's
& > dd ~ dt + dd {
  margin-top: 0.75em;
}
```