# How to style dt and dd so they are on the same line?

Tags: html, css

Using CSS, how can I style the following:

```
<dl>
    <dt>Mercury</dt>
    <dd>Mercury (0.4 AU from the Sun) is the closest planet to the Sun and the smallest planet.</dd>
    <dt>Venus</dt>
    <dd>Venus (0.7 AU) is close in size to Earth, (0.815 Earth masses) and like Earth, has a thick silicate mantle around an iron core.</dd>
    <dt>Earth</dt>
    <dd>Earth (1 AU) is the largest and densest of the inner planets, the only one known to have current geological activity.</dd>
</dl>
```

so the content of the `dt` show in one column and the content of the `dd` in another column, with each `dt` and the corresponding `dd` on the same line? I.e. producing something that looks like:

[image: table format]

Comment: Just as a useful note: if you wanna control the spacing between lines of dts and dds, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/896815/114029 These powerful tags make styling forms really easy and beautiful.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896815/css-dl-with-spacing-margin-between-the-dt-dd-pairs particularly the accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/896840/1037948

Comment: Please consider changing the accepted answer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44599527/3853934

Answer (score 155, accepted):

```css
dl {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ff0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}
dt {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  /* adjust the width; make sure the total of both is 100% */
  background: #cc0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}
dd {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  /* adjust the width; make sure the total of both is 100% */
  background: #dd0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Mercury</dt>
  <dd>Mercury (0.4 AU from the Sun) is the closest planet to the Sun and the smallest planet.</dd>
  <dt>Venus</dt>
  <dd>Venus (0.7 AU) is close in size to Earth, (0.815 Earth masses) and like Earth, has a thick silicate mantle around an iron core.</dd>
  <dt>Earth</dt>
  <dd>Earth (1 AU) is the largest and densest of the inner planets, the only one known to have current geological activity.</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Thanks! This CSS tip helped me to format my Zend Form without having to code form decorator classes.

Comment: You don't seem to be able to add a bottom margin or padding tow space out the "rows" using this method.

Comment: I recommend adding a `clear: left` to the dt style to ensure they stay inline even if they need to wrap.

Comment: The `* { ... }` statement makes everything lose the margin and padding, and removing it distorts the DL. Using a class won't do the trick either. It seems that if I want anything but the DL I'll have to go without margins and paddings everywhere... Or?

Comment: This behaves awkwardly when you select (double click) the first word in the <dd>. It also selects the text inside the <dt> unless there's whitespace (or an &nbsp; if you're using htmlmin) between the <dt> and <dd>.

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm. @Simon, the "clear: left" fixed a nagging problem I had with cascading items. All great now.

Answer (score 160):

**CSS Grid layout**

> Like tables, grid layout enables an author to align elements into columns and rows.
>   *https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout*

To change the column sizes, take a look at the [`grid-template-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns) property.

```css
dl {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content auto;
}

dt {
  grid-column-start: 1;
}

dd {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Mercury</dt>
  <dd>Mercury (0.4 AU from the Sun) is the closest planet to the Sun and the smallest planet.</dd>
  <dt>Venus</dt>
  <dd>Venus (0.7 AU) is close in size to Earth, (0.815 Earth masses) and like Earth, has a thick silicate mantle around an iron core.</dd>
  <dt>Earth</dt>
  <dd>Earth (1 AU) is the largest and densest of the inner planets, the only one known to have current geological activity.</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: This is _exactly_ what I want. https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid - not quite as universal as I'd like, but tolerably well supported.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. The other solutions have somre requirements liek a fix width for container or first column but this is perfectly dynamic :)

Comment: This solution works for me. To give a space between columns I just used `column-gap` instead of changing values of `grid-template-columns`. There's a `row-gap` property as well.

Comment: This is the future and the future is now. Would be grand if this got upvoted to the top.

Answer (score 141):

I have got a solution without using floats!

**check this on** *[codepen](http://cdpn.io/nvgCz)*

Viz.

```
dl.inline dd {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
}
dl.inline dd:after{
  display: block;
  content: '';
}
dl.inline dt{
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100px;
}
```

**Update - 3<sup>rd</sup> Jan 2017:** I have added flex-box based solution for the problem. Check that in the linked *[codepen](http://cdpn.io/nvgCz)* & refine it as per needs.

```
dl.inline-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 300px;      /* set the container width*/
  overflow: visible;
}
dl.inline-flex dt {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
dl.inline-flex dd {
  flex:0 0 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: left;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! That evil float just solved one problem while giving me two new ones (like no vertical align). Nice that it's gone now.

Comment: This works well with short text in the DD part; if the text is too long, it will wrap around and show under the DT part.

Comment: This works even if some items of the list are empty. Great!

Comment: @tjm1706: I think, the flex based solution could handle longer text case. thanks :)

Comment: @navaneeth Great sol'n.  To get dots between the word and definition I added: dl.inline-flex dt:after { content: "................" }  I actually use 150 dots here to ensure there are enough.  You also need to add white-space: nowrap to the dt

Comment: What if we don't want the dt to get half of the width and its width be driven by the length of the text in it. This can be done easily using tables, but I prefer to use dl with flexbox rather than tables for layout.

Comment: NP: `flex-flow: row;` should be `flex-direction: row;` if you want direction and wrap separated; otherwise, use `flex-flow: row wrap;` and remove `flex-wrap: wrap;`.

@smohadjer, change `dt` to use `flex: 0 0 auto;`, and `dd` to use `flex: 1 1 0;`.

Comment: @smohadjer, I spoke too soon. I assumed column-based shrink and auto would work here, but they do not because the `dt` and `dd` are like columns in a single row (`dl`).

Answer (score 61):

If you use Bootstrap 3 (or earlier)...

```html
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>Label:</dt>
    <dd>
      Description of planet
    </dd>
    <dt>Label2:</dt>
    <dd>
      Description of planet
    </dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: If you look at Bootstrap's CSS you can get an idea of how to style it even without using Bootstrap, too, though I do love that framework.  Here's a snippet, ignoring the media queries for responsive design for simplicity of an example:
dl{margin-top:0;margin-bottom:20px}
dt,dd{line-height:1.428571429}
dt{font-weight:700}
dd{margin-left:0}
.dl-horizontal dt{float:left;width:160px;clear:left;text-align:right;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap}
.dl-horizontal dd{margin-left:180px}

Comment: the `dl-horizontal` was actually dropped from Bootstrap 4. In BS4, you need to use grid classes instead.

Answer (score 22):

Assuming you know the width of the margin:

```
dt { float: left; width: 100px; }
dd { margin-left: 100px; }
```

Comment: I wouldn't call it clean, because you've hardcoded the margins in.

Comment: Clean: having a simple, well-defined, and pleasing shape. The answer is short. It solves the problem in three statements. Not having known the margin was not a requirement as part of the question.

Comment: Clean is generally used for markup in these styles of questions. Anyway, welcome to StackOverflow, and I recommend that you put those kinds of assumptions in the body of your question, just for clarity.

Comment: Note that `<dt><big>Mercury</big></dt>` distorts the required layout (?).

Answer (score 14):

Because I have yet to see an example that works for my use case, here is the most full-proof solution that I was able to realize.

```css
dd {
    margin: 0;
}
dd::after {
    content: '\A';
    white-space: pre-line;
}
dd:last-of-type::after {
    content: '';
}
dd, dt {
    display: inline;
}
dd, dt, .address {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
dt {
    font-weight: bolder;
}
dt::after {
    content: ': ';
}
.address {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
Surrounding

<dl>
  <dt>Phone Number</dt>
  <dd>+1 (800) 555-1234</dd>
  <dt>Email Address</dt>
  <dd><a href="#">example@example.com</a></dd>
  <dt>Postal Address</dt>
  <dd><div class="address">123 FAKE ST<br />EXAMPLE EX  00000</div></dd>
</dl>

Text
```

Strangely enough, it doesn't work with `display: inline-block`. I suppose that if you need to set the size of any of the `dt` elements or `dd` elements, you could set the `dl`'s display as `display: flexbox; display: -webkit-flex; display: flex;` and the `flex` shorthand of the `dd` elements and the `dt` elements as something like `flex: 1 1 50%` and `display` as `display: inline-block`. But I haven't tested that, so approach with caution.

Comment: seems like the only way how to achieve desired layout with flexible widths of both dt and dd

Answer (score 7):

[image: jsFiddle Screenshot]

See [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/thirdender/SqWLM/)

I needed a list exactly as described for a project that showed employees at a company, with their photo on the left, and information on the right. I managed to accomplish the clearing by using psuedo-elements after every `DD`:

```
.myList dd:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

In addition, I wanted the text to only display to the right of the image, without wrapping under the floated image (pseudo-column effect). This can be accomplished by adding a `DIV` element with the CSS `overflow: hidden;` around the content of the `DD` tag. You can omit this extra `DIV`, but the content of the `DD` tag will wrap under the floated `DT`.

After playing with it a while, I was able to support multiple `DT` elements per `DD`, but not multiple `DD` elements per `DT`. I tried adding another optional class to clear only after the last `DD`, but subsequent `DD` elements wrapped under the `DT` elements (not my desired effect… I wanted the `DT` and `DD` elements to form columns, and the extra `DD` elements were too wide).

By all rights, this should only work in IE8+, but due to a quirk in IE7 it works there as well.

Comment: Easily one of the best answers here.

Comment: My use case is fairly simple (I thought), and this exactly nailed what I was hoping to do: format a list of letter signers' names <dt> and their affiliations <dd>, with the affiliations wrapping nicely.

Answer (score 7):

You can use CSS Grid:

```css
dl {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
}
```

```html
<dl>
<dt>Title 1</dt>
<dd>Description 1</dd>
<dt>Title 2</dt>
<dd>Description 2</dd>
<dt>Title 3</dt>
<dd>Description 3</dd>
<dt>Title 4</dt>
<dd>Description 4</dd>
<dt>Title 5</dt>
<dd>Description 5</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's another option that works by displaying the dt and dd inline and then adding a line break after the dd.

```
dt, dd {
 display: inline;
}
dd:after {
 content:"\a";
 white-space: pre;
}
```

This is similar to Navaneeth's solution above, but using this approach, the content won't line up as in a table, but the dd will follow the dt immediately on every line regardless of length.

Answer (score 5):

I need to do this and have the `<dt>` content vertically centered, relative to the `<dd>` content. I used `display: inline-block`, together with `vertical-align: middle`

[See full example on Codepen here](http://codepen.io/astrotim/pen/JdBoJe)

```
.dl-horizontal {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;

  dt, dd {
    font-size: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
  }

  dt {
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
  }

  dd {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This works to display them as table, with border, it should be responsive with 3em the width of the first column. The word-wrap just breaks any words wider than the column

```
 dl { display:block;
      border:2px solid black;
      margin: 1em;}  
 dt { display:inline-block;
      width:3em;
      word-wrap:break-word;} 
 dd { margin-left:0;
      display:inline;
      vertical-align:top;
      line-height:1.3;} 
 dd:after { content:'';display:block; }
```

Comparison of `<table>` with `<dl>`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>

dl { display:block;border:2px outset black;margin:1em; line-height:18px;}  
dt { display:inline-block;width:3em; word-wrap:break-word;} 

dd { margin-left:0; display:inline; vertical-align:top; line-height:1.3;} 
dd:after { content:'';display:block; } 


.glosstable { border:2px outset #aaaaaa;margin:1em; text-align:left}  
.glosstable, table, tbody,  tr,  td, dl, dt {font-size:100%; line-height:18px;}

.glossaz { font-size:140%;padding-left:2em;font-weight:bold;color: #00838c; } 
td.first {width: 2.5em;} 
</style>
<body>
Table<br>
<table class="glosstable">
  <tr><td class="first">Milk</td>
  <td class="glossdata">Black hot drink</td>
</tr>
  <tr><td class="first">Coffee2</td>
  <td class="glossdata">Black hot drink</td>
</tr>
  <tr><td>Warm milk</td>
  <td class="glossdata">White hot drink</td>
</tr>
</table>
DL list <br>
<dl class="glosstablep">
  <dt>Milk</dt>
  <dd class="glossdata">White cold drink</dd>
  <dt>Coffee2</dt>
  <dd class="glossdata">Black cold drink</dd>
  <dt>Warm Milk</dt>
  <dd class="glossdata">White hot drink</dd>
</dl>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one possible **flex**-based solution (SCSS):

```
dl {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  dt {
    width: 150px;
  }
  dd {
    margin: 0;
    flex: 1 0 calc(100% - 150px);
  }
}
```

that works for the following HTML (pug)

```
dl
  dt item 1
  dd desc 1
  dt item 2
  dd desc 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you style the dt and dd elements, you might encounter a problem: making them have the same height. For instance, if you want to but some visible border at the bottom of those elements, you most probably want to display the border at the same height, like in a table.

One solution for this is cheating and make each row a "dl" element.
(this is equivalent to using tr in a table)
We loose the original interest of definition lists, but on the counterpart this is an easy manner to get pseudo-tables that are quickly and pretty styled.

THE CSS:

```
dl {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 clear:both;
 overflow:hidden;
}
dt {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 float:left;
 width:28%;
 list-style-type:bullet;
}
dd {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 float:right;
 width:72%;
}

.huitCinqPts dl dt, .huitCinqPts dl dd {font-size:11.3px;}
.bord_inf_gc dl {padding-top:0.23em;padding-bottom:0.5em;border-bottom:1px solid #aaa;}
```

THE HTML:

```
<div class="huitCinqPts bord_inf_gc">
  <dl><dt>Term1</dt><dd>Definition1</dd></dl>
  <dl><dt>Term2</dt><dd>Definition2</dd></dl>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't write `quatreVingtCinqPts`? :)

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution that seems perfect to me, but it needs extra `<div>` tags.
It turns out that it is not necessary to use `<table>` tag to align as in a table, it suffices to use `display:table-row;` and  `display:table-cell;` styles:

```
<style type="text/css">
dl > div {
  display: table-row;
}
dl > div > dt {
  display: table-cell;
  background: #ff0;
}
dl > div > dd {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-left: 1em;
  background: #0ff;
}
</style>

<dl>
  <div>
    <dt>Mercury</dt>
    <dd>Mercury (0.4 AU from the Sun) is the closest planet to the Sun and the smallest planet.</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>Venus</dt>
    <dd>Venus (0.7 AU) is close in size to Earth, (0.815 Earth masses) and like Earth, has a thick silicate mantle around an iron core.</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>Earth</dt>
    <dd>Earth (1 AU) is the largest and densest of the inner planets, the only one known to have current geological activity.</dd>
  </div>
</dl>
```

Comment: Why's it not XHTML compliant?

Comment: @DerickSchoonbee - Because `dl`s are only allowed to have `dt`s and `dd`s as children. `dt`s can only have inline elements as children. `dd`s, for some reason, can have block-level elements as children.

Comment: -1 Not valid HTML 4, XHTML 1, or HTML 5. Basically, you just want the `DI` element, [like myself](http://html5doctor.com/the-dl-element/#comment-37268). But with any such element, you don't need esoteric stuff like CSS tables at all... Anyhow, that element doesn't exist, and so you should not use it.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand The DI element is not valid HTML5 either

Comment: @AlexMorley-Finch: I know. That's why I said I *wanted* such an element (DI is from XHTML 2.0). By the way, Ian Hickson, the WHATWG HTML 5 editor, made me realise that the `run-in` CSS `display` value is exactly what I want (in my case, I want simple name-value metadata lists).

Answer (score 2):

I recently needed to mix inline and non-inline dt/dd pairs, by specifying the class `dl-inline` on `<dt>` elements that should be followed by inline `<dd>` elements.

```css
dt.dl-inline {
  display: inline;
}
dt.dl-inline:before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
}
dt.dl-inline + dd {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  clear:right;
}
```

```html
<dl>
    <dt>The first term.</dt>
    <dd>Definition of the first term. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque a placerat odio viverra fusce.</dd>
    <dt class="dl-inline">The second term.</dt>
    <dd>Definition of the second term. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque a placerat odio viverra fusce.</dd>
    <dt class="dl-inline">The third term.</dt>
    <dd>Definition of the third term. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque a placerat odio viverra fusce.</dd>
    <dt>The fourth term</dt>
    <dd>Definition of the fourth term. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque a placerat odio viverra fusce.</dd>
</dl

>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works on IE7+, is standards compliant, and allows differing heights.

```
<style>
dt {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 100px;        
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin:0;
}
dd {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin:0;
}
.cf:after {
    content:'';
    display:table;
    clear:both;
}
</style>

<dl class="cf">
    <dt>A</dt>
    <dd>Apple</dd>
    <dt>B</dt>
    <dd>Banana<br>Bread<br>Bun</dd>
    <dt>C</dt>
    <dd>Cinnamon</dd>
</dl>
```

[See the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9f4m/1/).

Answer (score 1):

In my case I just wanted a line break after each `dd` element.

Eg, I wanted to style this:

```
<dl class="p">
  <dt>Created</dt> <dd><time>2021-02-03T14:23:43.073Z</time></dd>
  <dt>Updated</dt> <dd><time>2021-02-03T14:44:15.929Z</time></dd>
</p>
```

like the default style of this:

```
<p>
  <span>Created</span> <time>2021-02-03T14:23:43.073Z</time><br>
  <span>Updated</span> <time>2021-02-03T14:44:15.929Z</time>
</p>
```

which just looks like this:

> Created 2021-02-03T14:23:43.073Z
> Updated 2021-02-03T14:44:15.929Z

To do that I used this CSS:

```
dl.p > dt {
  display: inline;
}

dl.p > dd {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
}

dl.p > dd::after {
  content: "\A";
  white-space: pre;
}
```

Or you could use this CSS:

```
dl.p > dt {
  float: left;
  margin-inline-end: 0.26em;
}

dl.p > dd {
  margin: 0;
}
```

I also added a colon after each `dt` element with this CSS:

```
dl.p > dt::after {
  content: ":";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue. I wanted the definition on the same line but only if the terms didn't flow past its start position. In that case I wanted it to be on a new line. After much trial and error I found a solution that's surprisingly simple using floats.

```
<html>
    <style>
        dl.definitions, dl.definitions dt, dl.definitions dd {
            display: block;
        }
        dl.definitions dt {
            float: left;
            clear: right;
            margin-inline-end: 2ch;
        }
        dl.definitions dd {
            float: right;
            margin-inline-start: unset;
            --definition-indent: 15ch;
            width: calc(100% - var(--definition-indent));
        }
    </style>

    <dl class="definitions">
        <dt> kjsfjk
        <dt> kjsfjk
        <dd>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
            sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
            aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
            ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
            esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
            sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui
            officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        <dt> kjsfjks sdf g fg dgf saf asf asf asdg ag
        <dd>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
            sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
            aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
            ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
            esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
            sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui
            officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        <dd> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
            sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        <dd> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
            sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        <dt> kjsfjks
        <dt> kjsfjks
        <dt> kjsfjks
        <dd>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
            sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        <dd> 
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
            sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </dl>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. It works like a charm

```
dl {
    display: inline-block;

    &::before {
        content: " ";
        display: table;
    }

    &::after {
        clear: both;
    }

    dt {
        margin-right: 5px;
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        clear: left;
    }

    dd {
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        padding-left: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually start with the following when styling definition lists as tables:

```
dt,
dd{
    /* Override browser defaults */
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
}

dt  {
    clear:left;
    float:left;
    line-height:1; /* Adjust this value as you see fit */
    width:33%; /* 1/3 the width of the parent. Adjust this value as you see fit */
}

dd {
    clear:right;
    float: right;
    line-height:1; /* Adjust this value as you see fit */
    width:67%; /* 2/3 the width of the parent. Adjust this value as you see fit */
}
```

Answer (score -8):

Most of what people here suggested works, however you should only place generic code in to the style sheet, and place the specific code in to the html code as shown below. Otherwise you will end up with a bloated style sheet.

*Here is how I do it:*

**Your style sheet code:**

```
<style>
    dt {
        float:left;
    }
    dd {
        border-left:2px dotted #aaa;
        padding-left: 1em;
        margin: .5em;
    }   
</style>
```

**Your html code:**

```
<dl>
    <dt>1st Entity</dt>
    <dd style="margin-left: 5em;">Consumer</dd>
    <dt>2nd Entity</dt>
    <dd style="margin-left: 5em;">Merchant</dd>
    <dt>3rd Entity</dt>
    <dd style="margin-left: 5em;">Provider, or cToken direct to Merchant</dd>
    <dt>4th Entity</dt>
    <dd style="margin-left: 5em;">cToken to Provider</dd>
</dl>
```

[Looks like this](http://www.ctoken.com/slideintro/country=US/language=en#4)

Comment: I would advise against repeating margin-left when it can be moved to the style sheet - they are there to prevent code duplication. Style sheet bloat can be counteracted with consistent design; but even then - if preventing bloat is to save network traffic, it is still saved by sticking it in the style sheet instead of the HTML.

Comment: -1 sorry. Don't use inline styles, unless you really REALLY have no other option, otherwise, you will end up with a really messy html markup to start with.

Comment: I think this is an anti-pattern.