# Display DL like a table

Tags: css, cross-browser

How to style definition list items to have each definition in one line?

HTML:

```
<dl>
    <dt>word</dt><dd>meaning</dd>
    <dt>word</dt><dd>meaning</dd>
    <dt>word</dt><dd>meaning</dd>
</dl>
```

Visual rendering I need:

```
*word* meaning
*word* meaning
*word* meaning
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713048/how-to-style-dt-and-dd-so-they-are-on-the-same-line/24520786#24520786

Comment: Answered in the 'duplicate' question - comparising <dl> to <table> http://stackoverflow.com/a/32727905/4258817

Answer (score 8):

Try this.

```
dt  {
    clear:left;
    float:left;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:26px;
    width:70px;
}

dd {
    clear:right;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:18px;
    padding:4px 0 4px 40px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works in my Firefox (haven't tested other).

Comment: Unfortunately this wouldn't scale with content like table does