# DL like a table

Tags: html, css

I have the following `DL` in a container that is 300px wide.

```
<style type="text/css">
dl {width: 300px}
dt {
  float:left;
  clear: left;
  width: 70px;
}
</style>
<dl>
  <dt>Row1</dt>
  <dd>Value1</dd>
  <dt>Row2</dt>
  <dd>Value2</dd>
  <dt>Row3 with longer title requiring line breaks</dt>
  <dd>Value 3</dd>
  <dt>Row4</dt>
  <dd>Value4</dd>
  <dt>Row5</dt>
  <dd>Value5.1</dd>
  <dd>Value5.2</dd>
  <dt>Row6</dt>
  <dd>Value6.1</dd>
  <dd>Value6.1</dd>
  <dd>Value6.1</dd>
</dl>
```

How can I align the items to look like a table, i.e.:

- Have `DT` in the left column and the `DD`s in the right column
- rowX and valueX top-aligned
- Multiple `DD`s  (for one `DT`) listed beneath each other

I found multiple related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713048/how-to-style-dt-and-dd-so-they-are-on-the-same-line), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284539/display-dl-like-a-table) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708788/showing-definition-list-with-dt-and-dd-on-same-row), but with neither I managed to top-align the different situation (`DT` being higher than `DD`, multiple `DD`s being higher than `DT`).

Comment: You mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/8VKng/

Comment: @ExplosionPills: Almost - only that I need multiple `DD`s to be beneath each other instead of next to each other...

Comment: If you use `width: auto;` on the `dt`s the only problem is the long titled ones...

Comment: @darkajax: but those long ones make it look ugly... :-(

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24520786/922522

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this solution will be in line with what you want with some minor tweaking.  Basically, you need to also float all of the `dd`s, but you need to clear them so that they stack vertically.  However, you cannot clear the first one since you need the `dt` to float to the left.  The `+` (next sibling) selector is handy for this since you can override the `clear` rule on the first `dd` that follows a `dt`.  You may also need to update the margins of the other `dd`s.

```
dl {width: 300px}
dt {
  float:left;
  clear: left;
  width: 70px;
}
dd {
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 70px;
}
dt + dd {
    float: left;
    clear: none;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8VKng/2/

Comment: Just tried to implement it in the real site, but got stuck again. If the `DT` has a line break, the next `DD` is misaligned - see the red DD in http://jsfiddle.net/8VKng/10/ . Thanks for your help!

Comment: @PeterAlbert unfortunately I don't think that a pure CSS solution is possible for *exactly* what you want because some measurements can't be known ahead of time, but this is as close as I could come: http://jsfiddle.net/8VKng/11/ -- `float: right` is used because otherwise there may be an extra margin to the left; if that's no good, you need a set width + `text-align: left` on the `dd`s as well: http://jsfiddle.net/8VKng/12/

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will try to make the best of it!

Answer (score 2):

I would use Bootstrap to handle the DL for you.

[Bootstrap Description List](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#typography)

They have two options and you could also customize their setup for your liking. Just a suggestion.

```
.dl-horizontal:before,
.dl-horizontal:after {
    display: table;
    content: "";
    line-height: 0;
}
.dl-horizontal dt {
  float: left;
  width: 160px;
  clear: left;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.dl-horizontal dd {
  margin-left: 180px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rzWnG/1/

This what bootstrap uses to make a horizontal DL. I motified it a bit to look better for what you are wanting. I used Explosion Pills html from his JSfiddle. For that, I will give him an upvote.

Try this. It would help a bit more to get an exact of what you are wanting.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use Bootstrap. :-(

Comment: @PeterAlbert I feel for you. Are you wanting it done similarly to the horizontal decsription list in the bootstrap docs I linked? I could check the bs core for ya and see how they styled it to assist.

Comment: Thanks - this solution works!!! +1. Just accepted ExplosivePills answer though, as it was slightly quicker! Thanks a lot for your effort!

Comment: Not that an answer selection matters but you are able to switch your answer. Glad I could be of help.

Comment: Just tried to implement it in the real site, but got stuck again - if I remove the `nowrap`, the alignment does not work - see http://jsfiddle.net/rzWnG/5/ . Thanks for your help!

Comment: What was the problem you encountered in the live site? The no Wrap is needed for the css I provided to look good. You adjusted the column widths as well. Did you get your problem fixed or do you still need help?