# Showing definition list with DT and DD on same row

Tags: css

I would like to show several rows of data which each have a title and some data on the same row.  This question has definitely been answered on SO (i.e. [How to style dt and dd so they are on the same line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713048/how-to-style-dt-and-dd-so-they-are-on-the-same-line)), however, it doesn't seem to work for me.  The following seems to work, except when a DD has not content in which a   fixes it.  I am interested it IE7+.  Is how I am doing this correct?  Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Untitled</title>
        <style>
            dl {width: 395px; font-size:12px}
            dd,dt  {padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;}
            dt {float:left; padding-right: 5px; font-weight: bolder;}
            /* dd {padding-left: 5px;} Does not work */
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <dl>
            <dt>DT Element 1:</dt><dd>DD Elem 1</dd>
            <dt>DT Second Element:</dt><dd>DD Element Two</dd>
            <dt>DT Elem 3:</dt><dd></dd>
            <dt>DT Element 4:</dt><dd>DD Elem 4</dd>
            <dt>DT Fifth Element:</dt><dd>&nbsp;</dd>
            <dt>DT Elem 6:</dt><dd>DD Element Six</dd>
        </dl>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to style dt and dd so they are on the same line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713048/how-to-style-dt-and-dd-so-they-are-on-the-same-line)

Comment: If you know that your question is an exact duplicate of an existing question, you should not open a new question but, if needed, ask for clarifications to the answers.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela  How best to do that?

Comment: Jukka is right. Float both the dt, dd, and give the dt a set width.

Comment: As I showed, each of my DTs have different amount of characters.  Giving the dt a set width would require a separate CSS declaration for each which is specific to the data contained.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that an empty `dd` is not generated and leaves an *empty* space (height:0px).

If you can, yes, simply put a `nbsp;` inside any empty element. It's the simplest solution that will work cross-browser.

A simple, pure css fix would be like this :

```
dd:after {content:"."}
```

But it adds a dot after each definition...

You can also simply set a min-height on your dd :

```
dt {clear: left;}
dt, dd {min-height:1.5em;}
```

(dt and dd min-height needs to be the same!)

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7MKQf/)

...You'll probably run into issue if your `dt` height is not regular (if it's sometime on 2 lines for example).

Comment: Thanks Kraz,  Ah, no height.  Now it makes sense.  Using CSS to add content seems a little odd to me.  Your min-height solution seems to work well.  May I ask why you included `dt {clear: left;}`?

Comment: it's for the case where `dt` height is greater than the `dd` height. You might not need it. In fact, I've [improved my solution](http://jsfiddle.net/7MKQf/1/) by floating both element and clearing the first one. No fixed width and both element height can be different. Just __remember to clear your 'dl'__! (or you'll probably have some issue.)

Comment: And the content part doesn't work with ie7 if I recall correctly.

Comment: Thanks again. By the way, your latest solution doesn't work with IE7, however, your first does.

Comment: @Kraz You should update your answer to include the version that floats both elements left and does away with the min-height as that is a much better solution than the first two.

Comment: @Justin if you provide a functionnal demo, sure, I'll add it.

Answer (score 0):

This works on IE7+, is standards compliant, and allows differing heights.

```
<style>
dt {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 100px;        
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin:0;
}
dd {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin:0;
}
.cf:after {
    content:'';
    display:table;
    clear:both;
}
</style>

<dl class="cf">
    <dt>A</dt>
    <dd>Apple</dd>
    <dt>B</dt>
    <dd>Banana<br>Bread<br>Bun</dd>
    <dt>C</dt>
    <dd>Cinnamon</dd>
</dl>
```

[See the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9f4m/1/).