# How to make inline text from Description List (dl)

Tags: css

So let's say we have this `<dl></dl>`:

```
<dl>
  <dt>Email:</dt><dd>contact@example.com</dd>
  <dt>Phone:</dt><dd>(555) 123-4567</dd>
  <dt>Bio:</dt><dd>Person's full-text bio, which spans multiple lines, and starts on the same line as the text <q>Bio</q>, just like the previous definitions. Any given solution should both allow this text to wrap below the &lt;dd&gt; and then provide a line break afterwards.</dd>
  <dt>Phone:</dt><dd>(555) 123-4567</dd>
</dl>
```

```
dt {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

dd {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

And I aso used this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ezrL3n5/) to work with it. <sup>[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085910/can-i-render-a-dt-on-the-same-line-as-its-dd?noredirect=1&lq=1)</sup>

Now the output is:

*Email:contact@example.comPhone:(555) 123-4567Bio:*

*Person's full-text bio, which spans multiple lines, and starts on the same line as the text Bio, just like the previous definitions. Any given solution should both allow this text to wrap below the  and then provide a line break afterwards.Phone:(555) 123-4567*

I want it to be inline like:

*Email:contact@example.comPhone:(555) 123-4567Bio:Person's full-text bio, which spans multiple lines, and starts on the same line as the text Bio, just like the previous definitions. Any given solution should both allow this text to wrap below the  and then provide a line break afterwards.Phone:(555) 123-4567*

Is there any CSS solution?

Comment: why are you posting an EXACT duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085910/can-i-render-a-dt-on-the-same-line-as-its-dd?noredirect=1&lq=1 and not mention it ? I understand you want a different solution but you should mention that this has been asked before. Do not ' own '  the solution of that question as if it was yours

Comment: I wrote "And I aso used this JSFiddle to work with it."

Comment: something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/3850bm6s/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove: `float : left`

add: `display: inline;` to whatever you want to be inline

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/47ntp52o/

read the display property doc here :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

extra: 
check out what does float do to positioning :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

Answer (score -2):

Try to add this in your CSS:

```
dl {
  min-inline-size: max-content;
}
```

```css
dt {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

dd {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

dl {
  min-inline-size: max-content;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Email:</dt><dd>contact@example.com</dd>
  <dt>Phone:</dt><dd>(555) 123-4567</dd>
  <dt>Bio:</dt><dd>Person's full-text bio, which spans multiple lines, and starts on the same line as the text <q>Bio</q>, just like the previous definitions. Any given solution should both allow this text to wrap below the &lt;dd&gt; and then provide a line break afterwards.</dd>
  <dt>Phone:</dt><dd>(555) 123-4567</dd>
</dl>
```

Then the last problem will be the `overflow-x`

> **Edit** - Notice that this solution has [compatibility issues](http://caniuse.com/#search=min-inline-size)

**Edit-Add** - I tried another solution:

```css
dt {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

dd {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

div {
  min-inline-size: max-content;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <dl>
     <dt>Email:</dt><dd>contact@example.com</dd>
     <dt>Phone:</dt><dd>(555) 123-4567</dd>
     <dt>Bio:</dt><dd>Person's full-text bio, which spans multiple lines, and starts on the same line as the text <q>Bio</q>, just like the previous definitions. Any given solution should both allow this text to wrap below the &lt;dd&gt; and then provide a line break afterwards.</dd>
     <dt>Phone:</dt><dd>(555) 123-4567</dd>
  </dl>
</div>
<div>
  <dl>
     <dt>Email:</dt><dd>contact@example.com</dd>
     <dt>Phone:</dt><dd>(555) 123-4567</dd>
     <dt>Bio:</dt><dd>Person's full-text bio, which spans multiple lines, and starts on the same line as the text <q>Bio</q>, just like the previous definitions. Any given solution should both allow this text to wrap below the &lt;dd&gt; and then provide a line break afterwards.</dd>
     <dt>Phone:</dt><dd>(555) 123-4567</dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

> This works as you want, but this requires to put `<dl>` tags inside each `<div>` tag

Comment: this way it makes all in one line... but I need it to spred into multilines

Comment: You should mention that this has compatibility issues https://caniuse.com/#search=min-inline-size

Comment: As far as I see this can be only achived with jQuery, but I wander if there is CSS solution.

Comment: Answer edited, let me know if you like the second solution

Comment: div cannot be a child of dl

Comment: Thanks about the information, is it correct now? @Temani Afif