# Align HTML5 Definition List like a table, without setting widths, and without Javascript

Tags: html, css, semantic-markup

The HTML5 DL element, (markup like):

```
<dl class="inline">
    <dt>Name</dt>
    <dd>Alex</dd>
    <dt>Age</dt>
    <dd>22</dd>
    <dt>Hobby</dt>
    <dd>Programming</dd>
</dl>
```

renders by default like this:

```
Name
    Alex
Age
    22
Hobby
    Programming
```

However I want it to be rendered like a table, where the columns line up:

```
Name    Alex
Age     22
Hobby   Programming
```

This can easily be done using css

```
dl.inline dt{clear:left}
dl.inline dt,dl.inline dd{float:left}
```

and by setting the widths of the DT elements

```
dl.inline dt{width: 100px}

     100px
<----------->
Name         Alex
Age          22
Hobby        Programming
```

Success!

The issue is, this requires setting the width to the longest text. This means the css depends on the html. Esentially EVERYTIME I create a new definition list, I have to create a new css class, find the longest word, and then add that to the css

```
dl.inline.dt-where-the-longest-string-is-email-address{width:86px}
```

**I want the DT elements to automatically be as long as the longest one is.**

This could EASILY be done using jquery. We basically loop the DT's and remember the longest. Then set all others within that DL to that length:

```
(function()
{
    // for every DL on the page, that has class 'inline'
    $('dl.inline').each(function(dl_idx, dl_node)
    {
        var dl = $(dl_node),  // the current DL
            longest = 0;   // the current longest

        // go through its DT elements
        dl.each(function(dt_idx, dt_node)
        {
            var width = $(dt_node).width();

            // if this width is larger than the largest so far
            if(width > longest)
            {
                // store this width as the new longest
                longest = width;
            }
        });

        // Set all the DT elements in this DL to the longest found
        dl.children('dt').width(longest);
    });
}());
```

This code may not be perfect, but it puts the point across.

**I was hoping for a pure css solution, that uses the browsers native code rather than javascript.**

HTML Tables use properties like `display:table-cell` although I have not been able to get anything to work...

The solution I am looking for:

- Does **NOT** change the DL markup
- Does **NOT** use javascript

If it turns out that such a solution is NOT possible. Or REQUIRES the markup to be different, then I suppose the javascript solution will have to do for now.

**I should probably state that the REASON I'm not just using a table, is because I feel the data is not tabular enough.** That kind of data is more like ONE ROW of a table. I feel like the Definition List better defines the relationships between the Key and the Value (i.e. Name -> Alex)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to style dt and dd so they are on the same line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713048/how-to-style-dt-and-dd-so-they-are-on-the-same-line)

Comment: That solution is not what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

Pure CSS solution:

**check my example on** *[codepen](http://cdpn.io/nvgCz)*

Comment: Interesting solution. I like how it's not floating. I wonder if there is a way without setting the width though, or the min-width. I'm looking for a dynamic solution

Comment: yeah. i am not sure without fixing any width. In this particular example, we cannot align the right side data if we do not set min-width/ width. And, anyways there should be a limit for its width. so u can use this. u can add a property like text overflow ellipsis after certain limit. Anyways, it depends on ur requirement :)