# How to style a list like the following?

Tags: css, html

I want to right and left align a list but i'm not sure the best way to do this with html and css.

I want it to look something like this.

```
    Name: John Doe
   Email: someone@example.com
Birthday: January 01, 1971
  Gender: Male
```

Comment: What you want is a [description list](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_dl.asp). That should make your life way easier.

Comment: Have you attempted anything yet? This question is far too broad to answer. There's many ways of doing this (inline-block, table, flexbox, to name a few)

Comment: I'm not sure how to even start this that's why I posed on here.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713048/how-to-style-dt-and-dd-so-they-are-on-the-same-line

Comment: How is this too broad? I asked a simple question on html/css formatting?

Comment: @Markaway If it's simple, try something?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the description list tag, 
fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jmhk9bjs/
more info here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl

It will be something like this

```
<dl>
    <dt>
        Name
    </dt>
    <dd>
        John Doe
    </dd>
</dl>
```

CSS

```
dl dt, dl.inline dd {
    float: left;
}
dl dd + dt, dl.inline dd + dd {
    clear: left
}
dl.inline dd + dd {
    float: none
}
dl.inline dt {
    font-weight: bold
}
```

Comment: `with html and css` Last time I checked, description lists are only HTML. He also wanted CSS. Which, incidentally, is why when I pointed him to description lists 45 seconds before you did, I gave it as a comment and not an answer. Add CSS and this will be a complete, helpful answer which I'll upvote. Don't add CSS and I'll downvote.

Comment: That answer does not work, even with the CSS.

Comment: How would I properly right align the "dt" and put 4px padding between the dt and dd?

Comment: It almost sounds like you don't know css at all

Comment: I'm not that great at it but I'm learning from SO.

Answer (score 0):

with a simple list, you may use `class` and pseudo elements : **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/IEnCe)**

```
<ul class="centerhem">
  <li class="Name">John doe</li>
  <li class="Email"><span class="Hide" data-name="J-doe" data-com="domain.org"></span></li>
  <li class="Birthday">January, 01, 01</li>
  <li class="Gender">Male</li>
</ul>
```

And some style:

```
.centerhem {
  list-style-type:none;
  display:table;
  border:solid;
  padding:0;
  margin:1em auto;
}
.centerhem li:before {
  content:attr(class)' : ';
  display:inline-block;
  width:5em;
  text-align:right;
  margin-right:0.25em;
  color:#A56F10;
}
li {
  color:#1A97D4;
  width:15em;
}
li span.Hide:before {
  content:attr(data-name)'@'attr(data-com);
}
```

Class can be reused any time.

data-attributes within the span is to *try* to hide email from spammer harvest.

Comment: I tried using this and everything remains left aligned.

Comment: Have you any evidence that hiding e-mails that way actually cuts down significantly on spam traffic to the address? Or did you just come up with it / read it somewhere, think it was cool, and then recommend as a best practice something that would be a pain to use and would screw with screen readers?

Comment: (Despite how it might come off, that's a genuine question. If that _does_ have a demonstrated and significant effect on spam traffic, it's good to have the data.)

Comment: generated content doesn't exist witout CSS and cannot be selected, as long as spammer robot do not look for it, they do not find it. i wrote TRY, and used data-attributes to break it into pieces. It is a cheap way :) . I gave already such an answer in here couple of days ago. I do not read that much :)

Comment: @ParthianShot , thanks for your feed back and interest, i obviously did not think about screen readers, do they really skip generated content ? just seen this http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201205/css_generated_content_and_screen_readers/ thx

Answer (score 0):

You can also use floating divs: http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/pnh920qn/

**HTML**

```
<div id="left">
    <div>Name</div>
    <div>Email</div>
    <div>Birthday</div>
    <div>Gender</div>
</div>
<div id="right">
    <div>John Doe</div>
    <div>someone@example.com</div>
    <div>January 01, 1971</div>
    <div>Male</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    color:#05BEE3;
}
#left {
    float:left;
}
#left>div{
    text-align:right;
}
#left>div:after{
    content:":";
}
#right {
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

Comment: I'm just wondering why this answer was downvoted? It does exactly what the OP asked.