# Is there a way to prevent a line break between two elements (dt and dd) without a wrapper?

Tags: html, css

It's for a definition list, which only allows `dt` and `dd` tags. It is not valid to wrap a `dt` and its associated `dd` inside of a `div`.
Example definition list:

```
<dl>
    <dt>Name:</dt>
    <dd>Nick</dd>
    <dt>Age:</dt>
    <dd>26</dd>
    <!-- etc -->
</dl>
```

I want the `dt` and `dd` tags to be inline-blocks that wrap. I want to allow up to two `dt/dd` pairs on one line, but I never want it to wrap after a `dt` tag. In other words, I never want "Name" and "Nick" to be on different lines. I never want "Age" and "26" to be on different lines either. Perhaps all four of them are on one line, or perhaps "Name" and "Nick" are on one line and "Age" and "26" are on the next line, depending on the viewport width.

I tried putting `&nbsp;` between the elements but that didn't work. I can't wrap the dt with its associated dd because technically that is invalid markup.

Is there any correct solution to this problem? Or do I have to abandon semantic principles in order to get the styling I want?

Edit: This is not a duplicate of [How to style dt and dd so they are on the same line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713048/how-to-style-dt-and-dd-so-they-are-on-the-same-line) because I said "I want to allow up to two dt/dd pairs on one line". Whether there is one or two pairs depends on variable content.

Comment: I'm not really sure if I understand your problem correctly but you could give you dt's and dd's a width of 25%, or you could make multiple dl's.

Comment: I can't make them 25% because the text content is unknown (inserted with a template engine). I want the text width to determine whether there are four elements on a line or two. As for your second solution, this would work buuuuuuut...they should semantically all be part of the same list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style dt and dd so they are on the same line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713048/how-to-style-dt-and-dd-so-they-are-on-the-same-line)

Comment: @BSMP but depending on the content there may be 4 elements on one line.

Comment: What's your browser support look like? Flexbox may be your answer.

Comment: I don't really worry about browser support because I can always hack in a fallback for old browsers. But even with flexbox I can't think of a solution.

Comment: Well, [I got somewhere](https://jsfiddle.net/osvd7xts/) - doesn't match your requirements 100% but it is semantic

Comment: chazsolo, thanks for the attempt. Problem is, the main requirement is that `dd` doesn't wrap by itself. It stays on the same line as its `dt`

Comment: Did you find a way? I am looking for a solution for exactly this problem.

Comment: Nope...I just wrapped them all in seperate dl tags. Let me know if you come across something.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `dt` and `dd` `inline` and emulate a line break `:after` `dd` like this

```css
dt {
  display: inline;
  font-weight: bold;
}

dd {
  display: inline;
}

dd:after {
  content: "\a";
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<dl>
    <dt>Name:</dt>
    <dd>Nick</dd>
    <dt>Age:</dt>
    <dd>26</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: OP wrote: "I want to allow up to two dt/dd pairs on one line"...