# why does font-family: monospace changes the layout of my <dl>

Tags: html, css

I am using some code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1713060/274677) on a question of how to align `dd` and `dt` elements on the same line and the results are good.

The following code:

```css
 dl {
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   background:#ff0;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
 }
 dt {
   float: left;
   text-align: right;
   width: 20%;
   background: #cc0;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;

   font-weight: bold;
   /* Question 2 */
   /* font-family: monospace;  */
   margin-right: 10%;
 }
 dd {
   float: left;
   text-align: left;
   width: 70%;
   background: #dd0;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   /* Question 1 */
   /* font-family: monospace; */
 }
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>cat</dt><dd>small, domesticated  feline</dd>
  <dt>bear</dt><dd>large omnivore (top land predator)</dd>
  <dt>giraffe</dt><dd>the most useless quadruped</dd>
</dl>
```

... produces this image:

[image]

However, when I try to apply `font-family:monospace` to either the `dd` or the `dt` elements the layout breaks.

E.g. if I remove the comment below the `Question 1` line this is what I see:

[image]

Whereas if I remove the comment below the `Question 2` line I get a less dramatic failure but still not pleasant to look at:

[image]

I would like to understand:

1. why `font-family: monospace` can upset the layout so much (particularly for the `dd` element)
2. how to fix that

Comment: give it a `line-height`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is the different line-height of the fonts used. Your system's monospace font is slightly smaller than the other font used. This leads to different heights of the `dd` and `dt` elements. Now, in the first case (`dd` is monospace), the second `dt` element is below the first `dd` because there is like literally one pixel left of the first `dt`'s height, so it gets placed there due to the floating.

If both are set to monospace, it looks good again because all elements have the same line-height again.

```css
 dl {
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   background:#ff0;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
 }
 dt {
   float: left;
   text-align: right;
   width: 20%;
   background: #cc0;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;

   font-weight: bold;
   /* Question 2 */
   font-family: monospace;
   margin-right: 10%;
 }
 dd {
   float: left;
   text-align: left;
   width: 70%;
   background: #dd0;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   /* Question 1 */
   font-family: monospace;
 }
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>cat</dt><dd>small, domesticated  feline</dd>
  <dt>bear</dt><dd>large omnivore (top land predator)</dd>
  <dt>giraffe</dt><dd>the most useless quadruped</dd>
</dl>
```

Alternatively, you can also explicitly set a line-height if you only want to have one of the two elements to use monospace font:

```css
 dl {
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   background:#ff0;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
 }
 dt {
   float: left;
   text-align: right;
   width: 20%;
   background: #cc0;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;

   font-weight: bold;
   /* Question 2 */
   /* font-family: monospace; */
   margin-right: 10%;
 }
 dd {
   float: left;
   text-align: left;
   width: 70%;
   background: #dd0;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   /* Question 1 */
   font-family: monospace;
 }
 dd, dt {
   line-height: 14px;
 }
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>cat</dt><dd>small, domesticated  feline</dd>
  <dt>bear</dt><dd>large omnivore (top land predator)</dd>
  <dt>giraffe</dt><dd>the most useless quadruped</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try giving font family to `dl` tag like this, if you want monospace for the entire content.

```css
 dl {
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   background:#ff0;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   font-family: monospace;
 }
 dt {
   float: left;
   text-align: right;
   width: 20%;
   background: #cc0;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   font-weight: bold;
   /* Question 2 */
   /* font-family: monospace; */
   margin-right: 10%;
 }
 dd {
   float: left;
   text-align: left;
   width: 70%;
   background: #dd0;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   /* Question 1 */
   /* font-family: monospace; */
 }
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>cat</dt><dd>small, domesticated  feline</dd>
  <dt>bear</dt><dd>large omnivore (top land predator)</dd>
  <dt>giraffe</dt><dd>the most useless quadruped</dd>
</dl>
```